# rg.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, webservice-client, http-status-code-403, transport

I am trying to access a webservices over https, I have the ssl certificates in place. However when I send the webservice request I am getting:

```
threw exceptionorg.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:296)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:190)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:371)
 at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:209)
 at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:448)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
 at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
 at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
```

Snooping on the wire show that the client is trying to connect to the server.
I am stumped as to what is causing this, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the web service Scope, we had the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can work out this was due to network errors. The client was configured to do one-way ssl only. Whereas the server was configured for two-way ssl.

Comment: I am also got the same problem. can you please let me know how you solve the problem.

Comment: this is my question in stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610258/getting-transport-error-in-apache-axis2-client

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this property and it should hopefully resolve the issue:

```
options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");
```

-Jasdeep

Answer (score 0):

if the webservice is in .NET and hosted on IIS , you can try the below

```
Open IIS console > Right click on Default Web Service - Properties >Uncheck "Http Keep-Alives Enabled"
```