# Getting Transport error in apache axis2 client

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ssl, axis

In my project i am  trying to create a rest client over `apache axis 1.62`, It was working before over `SSL`. Due to server configuration change and proxy has been added when i tried to access the `webservice` now i am get the following error

```
                org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: PortcullisNoMatch
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
            at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
            at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
            at com.services.integration.impl.live.LoginRepositoryStubImpl.login(LoginRepositoryStubImpl.java:305)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:124)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
            at com.db.mybank.backend.managers.ProfileManagerImpl.showMethodTimeAndObjects(ProfileManagerImpl.java:129)
            at org.appverse.web.framework.backend.api.aop.advices.ProfilingAdvice.invoke(ProfilingAdvice.java:38)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
            at $Proxy29.login(Unknown Source)
```

I am using the below code for the proxy authentication

```
                HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator basicAuthentication = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
            HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties();
            _operationClient.getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE,basicAuthentication);
            proxyProperties.setProxyName("proxy address");
            proxyProperties.setProxyPort(port);
            proxyProperties.setUserName("");
            proxyProperties.setPassWord("");
 _serviceClient.getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);
    _getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty( HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false" );
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem. I am accessing a webservice through proxy server from Excel's macro and I am getting the same error (403 PortcullisNoMatch) from proxy server. Have you already solved it, please?

Comment: that's perferct! And could you tell me where the problem was? Or how did you solve it? Thanks!

Comment: There are two issue 1. i used this code _getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty( HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false" ) in my clinet stub and 2. my firewall blocking is blocking the call so i properly setted the proxy confiuration according to the server.and it worked fine

Comment: Why don't you answer the question yourself and mark it as the answer so other people could know? @ramesh027